# Image delete button not functioning correctly?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a button that deletes an image which is uploaded on to my server. However, when I've uploaded an image then click delete nothing works it removes the image from the page but when I check the site directory it's still there. Plus there is no echo message appearing for DELETION COMPLETE either just DELETION FAILED, so it makes me wonder if it works at all and is just refreshing the page. No sure why this is, also is there a way to make it only show the loading image gif when the image is being rendered? Here's what I've got:

```
<?php
ob_clean();session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
        session_destroy();  
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }   

    $loadingimage = false;

    if(isset($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){
        $allowed = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
        $name = $_FILES["UploadFileField"]["name"];
        $tmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];
        $type = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['type'];
        $newName = "Image Attachment.jpg";
        $types = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
        $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(in_array($ext,$types)){
            move_uploaded_file($tmp, "UPLOADS/$newName");
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Your document has now been uploaded and is ready to send.</b></p></font>';
            $loadingimage = true;
        }

        else {
            if(!$tmp){
                echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">No document has been selected.</b></p></font>';
            }

            else {
                echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Uploaded document was an incorrect extension type, please use ".jpg", ".jpeg", or "png" only.</b></p></font>';
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        header( 'Location: Review.php' );
    }

    if (isset($_POST['delete'])){   
        if ($loadingimage == true){
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>DETLEION COMPLETE: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Image no longer available</b></p></font>';
            unlink('UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg');
            $loadingimage = false;
        }

        else{
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>DETLEION FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">No image available for deletion</b></p></font>';
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Attach Image</title>

        <link href="CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body link="black">
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
        <div id="borderDiv">
            <div id="navDiv">
                <div id="backNavDiv">   
                    <a href="CompletedBy.php"><font color="white"><p align="left"><b>&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;Completed By</b></p></font></a>
                </div>

                <div id="logoutDiv">
                    <a href="index.php?logout"><font color="white"><p align="right"><b>Log Out&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</b></p></font></a>
                </div>       
            </div>

            <div id="headerDiv">
                <p>Attach Image</p>
            </div>

                <?php
                    if($loadingimage == false){
                        echo '<div id="imageDiv"><img src="IMAGES/loading.gif"></div>';
                    }

                    else{
                        echo '<div id="imageDiv"><img src="UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg"></div>';
                    }
                ?>          

            <div id="loginBtnDiv">
                <div id="uploadAreaDiv">
                    <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
                    <label for="UploadFileField"></label>
                    <input type="file" name="UploadFileField" id="UploadFileField"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload"/>
                    </form>     
                </div>

                <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="delete" id="delete">
                    <input id="delete" name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>

                <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileForm" id="FileForm">
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
                </form>
            </div>             
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logoDiv">
        <img src="IMAGES/Logo.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You define `$loadingimage = false;`, then check if it's true or false. And it will always be false because of it.

Comment: You have no logic set to tell the script  where the file is located and therefore it can not be deleted. You also only make it possible to get to the delete portion only if the upload is happening simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented before, because you define `$loadingimage = false;`, you will only be able to delete the file if the file is being uploaded at the very same time - which seems rather pointless.

You should rather check if the file exists than using your `$loadingimage` variable for unlinking the file.

You could change

```
if ($loadingimage == true){
```

with

```
if (file_exists("UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg")) {
```

This will only delete the file if it exists, and prevent `unlink` from causing warnings.

Comment: This answered my question in the last answers comment thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$loadingimage`variable is always false. So you will never execute the `unlink()` function. If you think that it will be true because you set it to `true` in   `if(isset($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){}`, it will not, because your page is reloaded and you passed the `$_POST['delete']` to the page and `$loadingimage` variable will be set to false again. So remove the condition 
`if($loadingimage==true){}` and your code should work. I don't see any reason why you're making this condition at all.

Comment: Okay so i've done this and sure enough it works. But would I make it echo my DELETION FAILED: No Image available for deletion. ?

Comment: @MattHutch Qirel answered your the question below. :-)